# Вызов jQuery-функции для одного элемента

Tags: jquery

Всем, привет! Народ помогите разобраться, есть таблица, в ней картинки, при наведении надо добавлять стиль с рамкой, делать это надо с помощью jQuery.

Вроде все получилось сделать, но косяк в том, что при наведении на одну картинку подсвечиваются все, а надо чтобы только та на которой указатель, вижу, что функцию не правильно написал, но никак не могу сообразить, что надо сделать чтобы корректно заработало.

Помогите пожалуйста!

[Вот здесь накидал код](http://jsfiddle.net/QeVtR/1/)

Comment: А почему именно jQuery? Через css это одним правилом задается
    
    .link a:hover img {border:2px red solid;padding:5px}

Comment: Тоже вариант, но надо jQuery, рамка была просто примером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перемудрили. Достаточно такого кода:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("img").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '2px red solid');
    });

    $("img").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '0px');
    });

});
```

Разумеется, события, прописанные для ссылок, уже не нужны.

Comment: СПАСИБОМС :)

Comment: А вообще, подобная хренотень задается средствами css.

Comment: Маааленький нюанс, добавляет этот эффект ко всем картинкам, вот это не помогает **$(".link img")**

Comment: посмотрите мой пример

Answer (score 2):

Можно и так:

```
$(function(){

  $("img").hover(function() {
      $(this).css('border', '2px red solid');
    }, function() {
      $(this).css('border', '');
    });

});
```

Comment: блин ко всем картинкам применяется... :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QeVtR/3/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/QeVtR/2/

Comment: применяется только к картинкам внутри элемента с классом .link

Comment: Да,действительно! Спасибо! А поясните пожалуйста код, если не сложно, две функции через запятую, не сталкивался, мот есть ресурс где можно почитать?

Comment: конечно есть) api jquery называется: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ ;)

hover принимает на фходе 2 функции:

1аяя, которая выполняется при наведении мышки.
2ая, которая выполняется при убирании мышки с элемента.

вообще документацию по jquery почитайте, там много примеров использования. в яваскирпте, а тем более в jquery оно очень часто встречается, так что привыкайте :)

Comment: ну API понятно :), этим я пользуюсь регулярно, я просто впервые встречаю синтаксис перечисление функций через запятую :) Спасибо, за помощь!

Comment: пожалуйста. js позволяет такие конструкции, да и удобно это)